# Cannot Boot computer at all

Tags: boot, grub2

After trying to use the Boot Repair software via instructions, This was the pastebin that the program gave me.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6097372/

The Boot Repair program did not work or should I say did not repair anything or "change anything"

After tyring to use the live CD to manually fix grub, I am not able to mount anything in terminal.

according to the pastebin, I do not see where it has my main 40 gig SSD hard drive as being visible.

I am at a complete loss.  This is a single Boot computer with two hard drives and an 8gb thumb drive.

Any help would be appreciated.

John (TurboTech)

Comment: I failed to mention that this occurred after a simple software update.  When I tried to reboot the computer after a power down I got nothing.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu John! You can always [edit] your question by clicking on the `edit` link underneath the body of your post. So go ahead and use it, and add what you mentioned in the comment to the question!

Comment: What does `sudo hdparm -i /dev/sda` show?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the drive is toast and has reverted to its factory program mode, where it claims to be a blank 128 GiB drive.  You might check with the manufacturer to see if they have diagnostic tools.